# How to filter first appearance in table only

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is the table structure:

**tblApplicants**:

```
applicantID (index)   |     ApplyingForYear (nvarchar) 
------------------------------------------------------
1                           2013/14
11                          2013/14
13                          2013/14
12                          2013/14
15                          2013/14
21                          2012/13
```

**tblApplicantSchools_shadow**:

```
id (index)   |    applicantID    |    updated (datetime)   |   statusID (int)   |   schoolID (int)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                   11                  2012-09-24 00:00:00.000     3                   2
1                   13                  2012-10-24 00:00:00.000     4                   2
2                   15                  2012-11-24 00:00:00.000     3                   4
3                   13                  2012-03-24 00:00:00.000     4                   3
4                   12                  2012-09-24 00:00:00.000     4                   1
5                   21                  2012-11-03 00:00:00.000     5                   2
6                   11                  2012-09-04 00:00:00.000     4                   4
```

What I need to do is:

- get all applicants, that have an `ApplyingForYear` of '2013/14' in `tblApplicants`
- have a `statusID` of 4
- I only want to count them **once** - even if they appear twice or more in `tblApplicantschools_show`
- group the number of distinct applicants (as per the above) - by the `updated` date column (grouped by week)

So based on the sample data above, there should be 3 rows that come out, (because `ApplicantID` 13 appears twice and I only want him once).

This is how the result should look:

```
    Datesubmitted              TotalAppsPerWeek
    -------------------------------------------------------
    2012-10-24 00:00:00.000    1
    2012-09-24 00:00:00.000    1
    2012-09-04 00:00:00.000    1
```

This is what I have so far - but it results in 4 rows, not 3 :(

```
select  
   DATEADD(ww,(DATEDIFF(ww,0,[tblApplicantSchools_shadow].updated)),0) AS Datesubmitted,
   count(DISTINCT [tblApplicantSchools_shadow].applicantID) as TotalAppsPerWeek 
FROM tblApplicants  
INNER JOIN tblApplicantSchools_shadow 
      ON tblApplicantS.ApplicantID = tblApplicantSchools_shadow.applicantID
WHERE 
     ApplyingForYear = '2013/14' 
     AND [tblApplicantSchools_shadow].statusID = 4
GROUP BY 
     DATEADD(ww, (DATEDIFF(ww, 0, [tblApplicantSchools_shadow].updated)), 0)
```

**And here is a Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3aa61/42**

Comment: If both rows for ApplicantID 13 where in the same week, it would simply be a matter for adding ApplicantID to the group by, and probably would require adding it to the select.  However, since there is different values for Datesubmitted, what is the rule for which Datesubmitted and what TotalAppsPerWeek values you want?

Comment: I'm assuming now from the title "first appearance in table" that the smallest `id` is the row to keep. Correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your title, I'm assuming the one row you want from each applicant is the one with the smallest `id`. You can select one row per applicant ID with the `ROW_NUMBER()` function:

```
;with latestApplication AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(ww,(DATEDIFF(ww,0,[tblApplicantSchools_shadow].updated)),0) 
               AS Datesubmitted,
        [tblApplicantSchools_shadow].applicantID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [tblApplicantSchools_shadow].applicantID 
                           ORDER BY [tblApplicantSchools_shadow].id) 
            AS rn
    FROM tblApplicants  
    INNER JOIN tblApplicantSchools_shadow 
        ON tblApplicantS.ApplicantID = tblApplicantSchools_shadow.applicantID
    WHERE ApplyingForYear = '2013/14' 
    AND [tblApplicantSchools_shadow].statusID = 4
)
select Datesubmitted, COUNT(1) AS TotalAppsPerWeek
FROM latestApplication
WHERE rn = 1
group by Datesubmitted
order by Datesubmitted DESC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3aa61/57

Comment: perfect lc.
the answer is way over my head, so i have some reading up to do on the various pieces i dont know (with, partition, row_number() etc...) - but it works perfectly - thanks!

Comment: FYI `WITH` is defining a CTE (Common Table Expression). You should be able to search the docs for that and have a good read